# mongoose TypeError: Invalid schema configuration

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting this error while I am running my express app with mongoose. there is everything is all right in code part. but still now this error is showing. I can not identify exactly where the problem is.

CODE:
status: {
enum: ["active", "inactive"],
default: "active"
}

CONSOLE:
throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}` is not ` +
^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Active` is not a valid type at path `status.default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i didn't get much the problem but seems like you have a problem on declaring the enum values you can try to structure like this

```
status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['active','inactive'],
    default : 'active'
}
```

If this code didn't solve your problem could share the code for more information